# Two independent route systems with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

what I want to do is that my website has admin panel with the following routes /admin/.... and then the normal web would be /...

But the urls come together when I enter / works well but when I enter /admin you see the web menu and the admin menu when you would only have to see the menu of the administrator I leave the demo that performed in CodeSandBox, I hope you can help me.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-admin-users-5wzte

Greetings and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your routes in a Switch component. The Switch will return only the first matched route. More info is available here:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/basic-components

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because, your path `/admin` getting matched with your both `Route`.

You need to provide an [`exact`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool) prop,

```
<Route
    path="/"
    exact        //exact prop will help to match exact path
    render={userProps => (
    <Layout match={userProps.match}>
      <h2>Menu Web</h2>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />  //Add exact here also otherwise it will get match for path `/contact`
      <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
    </Layout>
    )}
/>
```

Also you need to make use of [`Switch`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch), which

> Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location.

Just wrap your `Route` with `Switch`.